# Сложное или простое предложение

Tags: синтаксис

> Здоровье, деньги, семья, будущее — жизнь задаёт множество вопросов.

Пожалуйста, подскажите — никак не могу разобрать. И каким членом предложения является ряд однородных?

Answer (score 1):

А может всё-таки простое с однородными членами и обобщающим словом "множество вопросов"? Сравним: "Множество вопросов задает жизнь: здоровье, деньги. семья...".

Answer (score 0):

Сложное бессоюзное предложение. Однородные члены — подлежащие в простом односоставном  назывном предложении.